# how to access xaml object in code behind for customized usercontrol?

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-4.0

Suppose I have a several usercontrol like:

uc1, uc2

uc2 include uc1 in xaml like

```
<my:uc1 x:Name = "myuc1" />
```

then in a new usercontrol code behind, I want to create instance of uc2 and access uc1 like:

```
uc2 mycontrol = new uc2();
uc2.myuc1.DataContext = myViewModel;
....
```

I got error because myuc1 is not accessible in code behind,  but I can access myuc1 in uc2 code behind!  Not sure why.

the error message said:
uc2 does not contain a definition for 'myuc1'

how to resolve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't you be accessing the variable's myuc1 and not the types?

For instance:

```
uc2 mycontrol = new uc2();
mycontrol.myuc1.DataContext = myViewModel;
```

Comment: thank you. I have typing mistake in the post. should be mycontrol.myuc1.DataContext = myViewModel; I got the error with undefined error.

Comment: In that case, I was not able to reproduce the problem. I created a quick app how you spelled out and I was able to get to myuc1.

Answer (score 0):

That's cause uc2 includes uc1. So, myuc1 is accessable in uc2 interanlly, because it will be compiled as private field. If you really want to make this instance public - create property in uc2.
E.g.

> > public uc1 MyUC1 { get { return myuc1 } }

Comment: This could be the case. While I was trying to reproduce it, everything was in the same assembly, therefore internally visible.

Comment: The description here is incorrect myuc1 is added to the class as a field with __internal__ accessibility not private. However I would agree that a public accessor property ought to be used to access it.

Answer (score 0):

The only reason I can think of why your code wouldn't work is because your new usercontrol is in a different project from your uc1 and uc2 controls.  The fields that represent named controls have internal accessibility and therefore are not available to other projects.

In my opinion not making these fields private isn't a good choice and in fact dynamically creating the fields at all isn't good.  Smacks of historical VB6/VBA forms to me.

I would recommend you add appropriate properties and methods to uc2 that will manipulate the uc1 rather than allow external code to fiddle around with uc1 directly.

If for some reason you can't take that approach consider placing wrapping access to the control in a public property.  Also consider creating an interface that uc1 can implement containing all the methods and properties you'd want to have access to, make this public property return that interface rather than the uc1 type.

Comment: you are right. Thanks. Got a more simple solution: use FieldModifer to resulve this problem.